# number of workers and processes in Julia

Tags: julia

in the distributed scheme, Julia distinguishes between workers and processes as far as I understand with the number of processes being +1 the number of workers. If in my machine there are only 10 cores, should I use 10 workers (`julia -p 10 file.jl`) or reserve 1 for the first process? Is the first process lightweight in general? What should I use for computations the number of workers or the number of processes? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adding to what @philipsgabler said.]

Assuming you will be using `@distributed for` loop or `pmap`, the process 1 will be responsible for controlling the computation and hence just will be waiting for the I/O from the workers. In some scenarios process `1` will be responsible for aggregating the data delivered by the workers. Hence you can resonably assume the process `1` is lightweight.

On the other hand if you use `@spawnat` than you have a strict control what is going on the Julia cluster. I would though though still recommend using process `1` as the process controlling the cluster rather than putting big workload on it.

Comment: This is the scenario that I visualized, that's why I asked if process 1 is lightweight. A simple related thing, if my machine has 8 physical cores (no hyperthreading) and I request 7 workers (-p 7) would Julia be able to use the extra core maybe for process 1 if its task becomes heavy? Thank you.

Comment: These are independent processes and hence the operating system is deciding on process affinity

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/distributed-computing/):

> Each process has an associated identifier. The process providing the interactive Julia prompt always has an id equal to 1. The processes used by default for parallel operations are referred to as "workers". When there is only one process, process 1 is considered a worker. Otherwise, workers are considered to be all processes other than process 1. As a result, adding 2 or more processes is required to gain benefits from parallel processing methods like pmap. Adding a single process is beneficial if you just wish to do other things in the main process while a long computation is running on the worker.

The command line option `-p auto` "launches as many workers as the number of local CPU threads (logical cores)".  That is, in addition to process 1 -- on my machine, `workers()` with `-p auto` returns the eight ids 2--9.

All processes are in principle equal, but definitions will only be visible in process 1, unless explicitely done so by, e.g., `@everywhere` (so, if at all, the workers are more lightweight).